# Dropbox bug: Missing text for Folder Settings

Tags: dropbox, linux-mint

So I was sharing a folder on Dropbox and decided to see its Folder Settings. I noticed then that some label text was missing from the form. It might just be me (Linux Mint), but can anyone tell me what these fields do?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The settings are similar to Dropbox for Business. But I wonder if it's just your browser not rendering it properly. You might try another browser to see. But to answer your question, the options are just share settings; who can be added, who can manage, and how links can be shared.

[image: Dropbox]

Comment: I was so stupid not to check the source but it's exactly like what you posted (with minor wording differences). What's weird is that I can't save it every time I choose to select, "No" in the last section.

Answer (score 0):

This is the only thing I see when I view a shared folder's settings. It seems that you have a Dropbox Team, which I don't have.

[image]

Comment: You mean I have more than you? Now that's odd. I'm actually more concerned with the last group of radio fields. It just says `Yes`/`No`.

Comment: Yeah. Based on the words in your screenshot, I think you are working with a Dropbox Team. I don't have a team set up so I can't see what you're seeing.